# Can teens travel alone in the EU?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, minor, travel

I am a Slovak EU citizen. A bunch of my friends and I are planning to go on a trip to the UK for 2 months when we are 15. Our parents are fine with it, but are concerned about whether or not this is legal.

How does EU-wide travelling work for persons who aren't yet 18? We'll all have passports and Slovak/EU IDs. Do we absolutely need to travel with an adult who will be legally responsible for us, or is it enough to have some sort of evidence/legal agreement that our parents let us?

Comment: Carry a parent signed permission with you, stating that you are allowed to do so.

Comment: This is probably better suited to http://travel.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no EU rules on whether and under which conditions unaccompanied minors are allowed to travel, and the competence hence rests with the Member States.

You are probably more proficient with Slovak rules on the matter, but judging by the information [provided by the UK Government](http://www.nidirect.gov.uk/children-travelling-alone), there should be no regulatory hassle. The most probable source of problems will be the airline, but at least [BA lets persons 12-17 years of age travel alone.](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/travel-assistance/children-travelling-alone)